# Logic: Dual of Laws and Double Implication

Tags: logic

"State the dual of the Absorption Law, $(p \lor  q) \land q ⟺ q$ "

I know that a duality involves changing all $\land$ to $\lor$ and vice versa, and changing all $T$ to $F$ and vice versa. But I'm not sure what to do with the ⟺ in this case. Do I leave it exactly as is, or is there a transformation involved? I've tried searching in textbooks and online but am having trouble finding a solid answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding question. As we don't have duality for ⟺

You have to take duality of only left side to prove it also ⟺ q.

Comment: Ah, that would make sense, thank you.

Comment: Mine pleasure :-)